# Plot issues in Jython script for ImageJ - reference sources welcome

Tags: plot, jython, imagej

I am encountering multiple issues when trying to display data generated by my Jython script. First, the style argument `Plot.CROSS` is ignored when using the following code, resulting in an unreadable line plot.:

```
p1=Plot("title","x","y", array1, array2, Plot.CROSS)
p1.show()
```

Second, this method glimpsed on a Java page doesn't return an error, but the plot does not display (empty plot, from -Inf to +Inf).

```
p2 = Plot("title","x","y")
p2.addPoints(array1,array2, Plot.CROSS)
p2.show()
```

Also, what is the correct format for changing the colour used? I have tried the `p1.setColor(Color.RED)` approach, but is comes back as undefined name.

I have some experience with Python, but none with Java. If anyone knows a handy reference for learning ImageJ scripting, I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your second example, you are missing to set the plot limits using `setLimits()`. The following example script creates a plot with three points marked by red crosses:

```python
from jarray import array
from java.awt import Color
from ij.gui import Plot

xArr = array([0.9, 2.0, 3.14], 'd')
yArr = array([2.3, 2.0, 13.14], 'd')

plot = Plot("Title", "X", "Y")
plot.setLimits(0.0, 5.0, 0.0, 20.0)
plot.setColor(Color.RED)
plot.addPoints(xArr,yArr, Plot.CROSS)

plot.show()
```

See the [javadoc of the `ij.gui.Plot` class](http://jenkins.imagej.net/job/ImageJ1-javadoc/javadoc/index.html?ij/gui/Plot.html) for the available functions.

For documentation about ImageJ scripting, see the following resources:

- [Scripting Help](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_Help) on the Fiji wiki
- The Fiji wiki page about [Jython scripting](http://fiji.sc/Jython_Scripting)
- [Albert Cardona's tutorial](http://www.ini.uzh.ch/~acardona/fiji-tutorial/index.html) on Fiji scripting with Python
- The [Scripting toolbox](http://fiji.sc/Scripting_toolbox) with some examples in various script languages

For advanced plotting in ImageJ, you might also want to look at the [JFreeChart library](http://www.jfree.org/jfreechart/api/javadoc/index.html) that ships with Fiji and is used by some of its plugins.